# Fedora doesn't recognize the wifi adapter

Tags: linux, fedora

I have a plug-n-play wifi adapter that doesn't get recognized by Fedora. I'm very new to to Linux but so far what I've googled tells me that Fedora has an issue with realtek adapters. I've found a series of steps that supposedly fixes the issue but didn't help me. Here's the tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PLFEF5JEkc

In the last step when installing the dkms-install.sh, I recevied an error in the terminal about my kernel version. I rebooted and now the terminal says:

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
[sudo] password for suleyman: 
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already built for kernel 6.1.9-200.fc37.x86_64 (x86_64), skip. You may override by specifying --force.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already installed on kernel 6.1.9-200.fc37.x86_64 (x86_64), skip. You may override by specifying --force.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi, at least the module is already present on your machine and in this case you cannot recreate it (except as said by --force in dkms-install.sh arguments). I would try to check with "lsmod" or "sudo lsmod" in order to check if the module is really instantiated in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ran the command you suggested but didn't see 'rtl8821ce' there

Comment: Any help? https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/install-realtek-rtl8821ce-wifi-driver/9170